# Optimize function's parameters with conditions (python)

Tags: python, testing, optimization

I begin by saying that I am totally new to this branch of programming, but i think that scipy optimization could be the solution.
I need to find the parameters that return the highest result in a function, but only if the result respect a condition.

The function is so long and takes more than 40 parameters, so it's impossible and too slow to brute-force them, the function returns 2 arrays of the same length in output.

```
constant = [1,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,7,8]
def fun(constant, length, period, multiplier, factor, ... ):

     do long and complicated calculations

     return array1, array2
```

Now, what I need is to find the parameters that returns the highest `array1[-1]` value`if max(array2) < 40`(for example), and then print them.

All parameters (length, period, multiplier, factor) works in a range from 2 to 200. Instead `constant`, obviously, should not be affected from the optimization.

I tried looping over all parameters by the ranges and execute calculation once by once, but it's very inefficent, intricate, and I think is not giving the best results.

**How can I perform this type of parameter optimization?**

Comment: Do you need to find the verifiably best solution, or just a "good enough" one? For the latter, you could just try random combinations for some predefined time.

Comment: From Scipy's options, [`scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.9.2/reference/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#scipy.optimize.differential_evolution) seems like it would fit your use case.

Comment: I could accept both, I just need to replace 900 lines of loop which tests parameter's values sequentially. How I could apply your solution? @AKX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build from scratch, a simple completely random "good enough" solver might look like this.

The solver is the first function, the rest are your (user) functions.

You need

- your target *long and complicated function*
- a function that returns a score for a given generated result (or zero if the result is invalid)
- a dictionary of functions that return values for each argument to try.

```
import random
import time


def find_solution(
    target_function,
    score_solution,
    param_generators,
    max_iterations=10_000_000,
    max_time=60,
):
    best_solution = None
    best_score = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(max_iterations):
        params = {param: gen() for param, gen in param_generators.items()}
        solution = target_function(**params)
        score = score_solution(solution)
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_solution = (params, solution)
            print(f"{i} / New best solution: {best_solution}")
        if time.time() - start_time > max_time:
            print(f"{i} / Time limit reached")
            break
    return (best_solution, best_score)


def fun(constant, length, period, multiplier, factor):
    a = constant * length * period * multiplier * factor
    b = length * period
    return (a, [b])


def sol_scorer(sol):
    if max(sol[1]) < 40:  # Invalid; return 0
        return 0
    return sol[0]


def main():
    constants = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    param_generators = {
        "constant": lambda: random.choice(constants),
        "length": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
        "period": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
        "multiplier": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
        "factor": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
    }
    res = find_solution(
        fun,
        sol_scorer,
        param_generators,
        max_iterations=10_000_000,
        max_time=10,
    )
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

On my machine, this prints out e.g.

```
227838 / New best solution: ({'constant': 8, 'length': 98, 'period': 93, 'multiplier': 96, 'factor': 99}, (692955648, [9114]))
1085159 / New best solution: ({'constant': 8, 'length': 98, 'period': 99, 'multiplier': 91, 'factor': 100}, (706305600, [9702]))
1447216 / New best solution: ({'constant': 8, 'length': 99, 'period': 97, 'multiplier': 97, 'factor': 97}, (722837016, [9603]))
2325989 / Time limit reached
(({'constant': 8, 'length': 99, 'period': 97, 'multiplier': 97, 'factor': 97}, (722837016, [9603])), 722837016)
```

---

## With sequential combinations

Adding an option to always try some combinations isn't much more code; see below.

```
import random
import time
from itertools import product
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Iterable


def find_solution(
    target_function: Callable[..., Any],
    score_solution: Callable[[Any], float],
    param_generators: dict[str, Callable[[], Any]],
    sequential_combination_generator: Optional[Iterable[dict]] = None,
    max_iterations: int = 10_000_000,
    max_time: float = 60.0,
) -> tuple[Any, float]:
    best_solution = None
    best_score = 0.0
    start_time = time.time()
    if sequential_combination_generator is None:
        sequential_combination_generator = [{}]

    try:
        for sequential_combination in sequential_combination_generator:
            print(f"Trying {max_iterations} w/: {sequential_combination}")
            for i in range(max_iterations):
                # Merge the sequential params with the randomly generated params
                params = {
                    **sequential_combination,
                    **{param: gen() for param, gen in param_generators.items()},
                }
                solution = target_function(**params)
                score = score_solution(solution)
                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                    best_solution = (params, solution)
                    print(f"Iteration {i}: New best solution: {best_solution}")
                if time.time() - start_time > max_time:
                    raise TimeoutError(f"Time limit reached")
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
    return (best_solution, best_score)


def generate_parameter_combinations(sequential_params: dict[str, list]) -> Iterable[dict]:
    # Break the sequential_params dict into keys and values
    keys, values = zip(*sequential_params.items())
    # Yield each combination as a dict
    for combination in product(*values):
        yield dict(zip(keys, combination))


def fun(constant, length, period, multiplier, factor):
    a = constant * length * period * multiplier * factor
    b = length * period
    return (a, [b])


def sol_scorer(sol):
    if max(sol[1]) < 40:  # Invalid; return 0
        return 0
    return sol[0]


def main():
    constants = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    # All of these combinations will exhaustively tried
    sequential_params = generate_parameter_combinations(
        {
            "length": [10, 20, 30, 40],
            "period": [40, 30, 20, 10],
        }
    )
    # You can also pass in just a list of dicts, á la
    # sequential_params = [
    #     {"length": 10, "period": 40},
    #     {"length": 20, "period": 30},
    # ]

    # These will be randomly generated
    param_generators = {
        "constant": lambda: random.choice(constants),
        "multiplier": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
        "factor": lambda: random.randint(1, 100),
    }
    res = find_solution(
        fun,
        sol_scorer,
        param_generators=param_generators,
        sequential_combination_generator=sequential_params,
        max_iterations=10_000,  # Limit for each sequential combination
        max_time=10,  # Total time limit
    )
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This prints out e.g.

```
Trying 10000 w/: {'length': 10, 'period': 40}
Iteration 0: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 2, 'multiplier': 95, 'factor': 64}, (4864000, [400]))
Iteration 1: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 7, 'multiplier': 73, 'factor': 93}, (19009200, [400]))
Iteration 71: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 6, 'multiplier': 96, 'factor': 93}, (21427200, [400]))
Iteration 248: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 80, 'factor': 89}, (22784000, [400]))
Iteration 595: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 79, 'factor': 97}, (24521600, [400]))
Iteration 679: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 7, 'multiplier': 96, 'factor': 99}, (26611200, [400]))
Iteration 722: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 98, 'factor': 93}, (29164800, [400]))
Iteration 6065: New best solution: ({'length': 10, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 98, 'factor': 94}, (29478400, [400]))
Trying 10000 w/: {'length': 10, 'period': 30}
Trying 10000 w/: {'length': 20, 'period': 40}
Iteration 0: New best solution: ({'length': 20, 'period': 40, 'constant': 7, 'multiplier': 70, 'factor': 79}, (30968000, [800]))
Iteration 26: New best solution: ({'length': 20, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 96, 'factor': 63}, (38707200, [800]))
Iteration 54: New best solution: ({'length': 20, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 81, 'factor': 78}, (40435200, [800]))
Iteration 80: New best solution: ({'length': 20, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 80, 'factor': 97}, (49664000, [800]))
...
Iteration 4500: New best solution: ({'length': 40, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 94, 'factor': 93}, (111897600, [1600]))
Iteration 5638: New best solution: ({'length': 40, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 96, 'factor': 97}, (119193600, [1600]))
Iteration 6006: New best solution: ({'length': 40, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 99, 'factor': 99}, (125452800, [1600]))
Trying 10000 w/: {'length': 40, 'period': 30}
(({'length': 40, 'period': 40, 'constant': 8, 'multiplier': 99, 'factor': 99}, (125452800, [1600])), 125452800)
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! What I have to put instead of random.randint() for testing the parameters sequentially? (length = 1, 2, 3, 4 ... and then period = 1, 2, 3, 4 ... ecc.)

Comment: @JCFIVE Sure, that's not that hard to add. See my edit :)

Comment: Men u're the GOAT!!! <3